# error "No active context found to set property" in azure

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

`const httpContext = require('request-context');
const app = express();
app.use(httpContext.middleware('request'));

httpContext.set('xxxxx', 'jnsdkj');
`
Its throwing an error 'No active context found to set property '
its working locally but not working in azure
it had worked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locally I'm using node version 8.7.0 in azure. It's allowing up to node version 10.0 if we don't mention specified version in the `package.json` file azure uses latest versions.

To avoid this confusion, in package.json mention version which you are developing:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "8.7.0"  // mentioning >= causes to use latest version
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the package [request-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-context) and created a sample azure web app to check this issue.

**app.js**

```html
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const httpContext = require('request-context')
app.use(httpContext.middleware('request'))
app.use(cookieParser())

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        var cookie = req.cookies.uname;
        console.log("usercookie:"+cookie);
        if(cookie!=undefined){
        // set the user who made this request on the context
            httpContext.set('request:user', {username:cookie,loggedTime:req.cookies.loggedTime});
        }
        next();
});

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    var user=req.query.name;
    if(user==undefined)
       res.send('you need to pass the username.');
    else{
        //set a cookie
        res.cookie('uname',user, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
        res.cookie('loggedTime',new Date(), { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
        console.log('cookie created successfully');
        res.send('login successed.');
    }
 });

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World!');
    });

app.get('/me',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('Hello World!'+httpContext.get('request:user.username')+",loggedTime:"+httpContext.get('request:user.loggedTime'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

**Package.json**

```html
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "request-context": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

**TEST:**

```
https://brucenode.azurewebsites.net/login?name=bruce

https://brucenode.azurewebsites.net/me
```

> httpContext.set('xxxxx', 'jnsdkj'); ` Its throwing an error 'No active context found to set property '

I assumed that you may need to check your code and verify that where you invoke `httpContext.set`. For Azure web app, you could also [Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) to troubleshoot this issue.